# parsing date/time to localtimezone

Tags: android, try-catch, date

I am trying to parse a date/time json from server side inside bind viewholder.
The date string am trying to parse is this:

```
2018-06-25T08:06:52Z
```

Here is the code that I am using ( got it from another stack overflow thread)

```
  try {


           SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
           df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Nairobi"));
           Date date = df.parse(timeToConvert);
           df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
           String formattedDate = df.format(date);
           String trimmed = formattedDate.substring(11,16);
           myViewHolder.date_TV.setText(trimmed);

       }catch (Exception e){

       }
```

However this does not work, the time set to the text view is the same as before parsing.

Comment: From API level 26 you can use `java.time.Instant` and related classes.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Instant To fill the comment of Arnold

Comment: As the previous comments suggest, consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. The modern `OffsetDateTime` will parse your string without any explicit formatter. Convert to you time zone, then to `LocalTime`, truncate to whole minutes, print and you’re done.

Comment: okay. Let me try that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String timeToConvert = "2018-06-25T08:06:52Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(timeToConvert);
    LocalTime time = inst.atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Nairobi"))
            .toLocalTime()
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println("Time in Nairobi: " + time);
```

This prints:

> Time in Nairobi: 11:06

I am using `java.time`, in this case the backport to Java 6 and 7. This backport is available in an Android edition too, which you may use for low Android API levels. My imports are:

```
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;
```

If you need the time string for an API that requires this format, you’re fine. If you are after a time string for presentation to a user, consider using Java’s built-in format instead:

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = inst.atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Nairobi"));
    System.out.println("Formatted: " + dateTime.format(timeFormatter));
```

I tried running this in Swahili (sw_KE) locale and got:

> Formatted: 11:06 AM

Apparently this locale uses the English AM/PM way of notating times (I got the same result in Kikuyu and Kalenjin locales). In UK locale I get the same format as before:

> Formatted: 11:06

I am using and suggesting `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. For anyone reading along and using Java 8 or later or programming for Android API level 26 or higher, you don’t need the backport mentioned. Just import the built-in date-time classes from `java.time` with subpackages instead of the above mentioned ones.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your error comes from hardcoding the `Z` in the date-time string as a literal. It’s a UTC offset of zero, and when you don’t parse it as such, the date-time string will be parsed in the time zone of your `SimpleDateFormat`, Africa/Nairobi, which is incorrect for your string.

IMHO you shouldn’t want to use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date` at all, though. Those classes are long outdated and the first in particular has proven troublesome. I always use `java.time` instead.

Another tip: Don’t swallow exceptions. Don’t leave your `catch` block empty. Report the exception in some noticeable way. This is your chance to discover when something goes wrong in your code.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer is detailed and  very helpful. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

> The time set to the text view is the same as before parsing.

This is because you're not passing in a new `SimpleDateFormat`.

Try this:

```
final String serverDate = "2018-06-25T08:06:52Z"
final SimpleDateFormat serverDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
final SimpleDateFormat yourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // put whatever you want here!

try {
    final Date date = serverDate.parse(serverDateFormat);
    final String formattedDate = yourDateFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

---

This way you're interpreting the `String` with the server format into a pure `Date` object. You're then free to do what you wish with that object and turn it into whichever format you want (by providing your new format).

For more information on building your date format pattern, see [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Thanks but the serverDate.parse has an error...cannot resolve method parse(java.text.SimplDateFormat)

Comment: It should be `final Date date = serverDateFormat.parse(serverDate);`. I suspect it doesn’t work correctly, though. It repeats the error of hardcoding the `Z` in the format pattern string as in the question.