# Kotlin Unparseable date - ParseException error

Tags: java, date, datetime, kotlin, simpledateformat

I'm seeing the following error when trying to parse a date string, can anyone point me in the right direction to parse this date string?

```
"2019-01-22T12:43:01Z"
```

Error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-01-22T12:43:01Z"
```

Code:

```
package ch02.ex1_1_HelloWorld

import java.lang.Exception
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Locale
import java.util.Date
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

const val SERVER_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SS'Z'" 
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.US)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    timeSince("2019-01-22T12:43:01Z")
}

fun timeSince(dateStr: String) {
    var diff : Long = 0
    try {
        diff = sdf.parse(dateStr).time - Date().time      
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        print(e)
    }
    "${TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)} h ago"
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android)

Comment: This question may also have a duplicate of [parsing date/time to localtimezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206465/parsing-date-time-to-localtimezone) in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your input does not contain milli seconds, you can remove the `:SS` in the pattern:

```
const val SERVER_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

And I would suggest to use `java.time` package.

Answer (score 5):

### java.time

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

fun timeSince(dateStr: String): String {
    val diffHours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(Instant.parse(dateStr), Instant.now())
    return "%d h ago".format(diffHours)
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
fun main() {
    println(timeSince("2019-01-22T12:43:01Z"))
}
```

This just printed:

> 236 h ago

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Compared to the old classes `Date` and not least `SimpleDateFormat` I find it so much nicer to work with. The method above will throw a `DateTimeParseException` if the string passed to it is not in ISO 8601 format. For most purposes this is probably better than returning `0 h ago`. The method is tolerant to presence and absence of (up to 9) decimals on the seconds, so accepts for example `2019-01-22T12:43:01.654321Z`.

Don’t we need a formatter? No. I am taking advantage of the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format, the format that the modern date and time classes parse (and also print)  as their default.

### I wish I could use `ChronoUnit` and `Instant`

Edit:

> I wish I could use ChronoUnit & Instant, but it requires a min V26 of Android. My current min is 23.

java.time works nicely on older Android devices too. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### What went wrong in your code?

I see two bugs in the code in your question:

1. As 竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 already pointed out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475974/5772882), your format expects 4 parts between `T` and `Z`, separated by colons, but your string has only three parts there. With `SimpleDateFormat` using two `SS` for fraction of second is also wrong since uppercase `S` is for milliseconds, so only three `SSS` would make sense (by contrast, with the modern `DateTimeFormatter` `S` is for fraction of second, so any number (up to 9 `SSSSSSSSS`) makes sense).
2. You are treating the `Z` in the string as a literal. It’s a UTC offset of zero and needs to be parsed as such, or you will get an incorrect time (on the vast majority of JVMs).

### Links

- [TiiJ7’s code on pl.kotl.in](https://pl.kotl.in/SyG51ab4N)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I wish I could use ChronoUnit & Instant, but it requires a min V26 of Android. My current min is 23.

Comment: You hadn’t told us this was for Android, though your SO user name of course gave a hint. Using `ChronoUnit` and `Instant` on API level 23 just requires using the backport. Your wish has come true. See my edit.

Comment: Didn't work, until single quotes were added around Z - **'Z'**

Comment: As in `2019-01-22T12:43:01'Z'`?? @JASKIER That’s very weird. It doesn’t work *with* those for me.

Comment: @JASKIER It works on https://pl.kotl.in/SyG51ab4N (just now it printed `19532 h ago`).

Answer (score 0):

My original value from server is:

```
2021-04-08T11:27:40.278Z
```

You can simply, make this shorter.
With **kotlin**, 2021:

```
// Read the value until the minutes only
val pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
val serverDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault())
// Format the date output, as you wish to see, after we read the Date() value
val userPattern = "dd MMMM, HH:mm"
val userDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(userPattern, Locale.getDefault())

val defaultDate = serverDateFormat.parse(INPUT_DATE_STRING)
if ( defaultDate != null ) {
   val userDate = userDateFormat.format(defaultDate)
   textView.text = userDate
}
```

*Result:*

> 08 April, 11:27

Comment: This will give you a `Date` with the wrong value. The `Z` is an offset of 0 from UTC and needs to be parsed as such, or the device default time zone will be used instead leading to a wrong result.

Comment: @OleV.V. My server is located in the same country. We read data from the server as I see, therefore you will see the same time for each device. I think this is enough for this kind of question. However, none of the previous answers helped me in some cases.