# Get time in specific format from timestamp including TimeZone

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

I have a simple function to extract time from timestamp which is String.

```
timestamp(input)  : "2020-08-13T09:33:17Z"
outputTime(output): "09:33"
desired output    : "12:33"
```

function:

```
fun getTimeFromTimestamp(timestamp: String): String {
    val inputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'", Locale.getDefault())
    val time = inputFormat.parse(timestamp) ?: Date()
    val outputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
    val outputTime = outputFormat.format(time)

    return outputTime
}
```

Problem is that it does not take in effect of timezone in the output, which is `GMT+3` in this case.

You can see my debug [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t71Va.png)

How can I make sure that time is displayed including timezone that comes with it (GMT+3)?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parsing date/time to localtimezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206465/parsing-date-time-to-localtimezone)

Comment: You may also want to look at [Android Studio Convert ISO string to “America/New_York” when adding to event to calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670961/android-studio-convert-iso-string-to-america-new-york-when-adding-to-event-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputtime is in that format because you specified it as so ( `HH:mm` ) in this line

```
val outputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
```

if you want it to include the time zone append the time zone to the output string

## edit

`"HH:mm zZ"` seems to be doing the trick for me check out this [fiddle](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: To add to this: "Z" is for the timezone! So for example "HH:mm \'Z\'" would give you 09:54 GMT+3. Other possible values that can be used in the formatter can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @RobbeRoels Changing "HH:mm" to "HH:mm Z" returns 09:52 +0300 not 12:52.

Comment: @Ole V.V. edit clears up the air I would recommend his answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you import your start time `"2020-08-13T09:33:17Z"` **AS** `GMT+3` and then try to format it to `GMT+3`. Try and format your import date to `GMT+0` and then keep the format for your output to `GMT+3`

You can see this answer for more on how to set the timezone on your SimpleDateFormat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124407/4383500

This should convert your time from a GMT timestamp to the local time

```
  fun getTimeFromTimestamp(timestamp: String): String {
        val inputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'")
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        val time = inputFormat.parse(timestamp) ?: Date()
        val outputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm ,z")
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        val outputTime = outputFormat.format(time)
    return outputTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LocalDateTime` [java.time] instead as `SimpleDateFormat`  is not recommended in 2020.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774455/13031115)

Comment: I agree in java.time, not in `LocalDateTime`. I suggest `Instant.parse("2020-08-13T09:33:17Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Tallinn")).toLocalTime()`. It yields `12:33:17`. Or one may use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting the `ZonedDateTime` from `atZone()` directly into the desired format, for excample, `12:33`. One should substitute the desired time zone, of course (and not use a naked offset like `+03:00`).